# How To Customize GTK Theme Used By Gedit in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, themes, gtk, gedit

I installed Lubuntu 16.04, but needed the Gedit editor for programming. Unfortunately when I installed it, it used a GTK window theme that I found to be quite undesirable. I wanted to change the way the max, min, and close icons look. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Is there a way to customize this theme on Lubuntu 16.04? Also, is it using Qt, GTK1, GTK2, or GTK3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to user *ducasse* on #ubuntu of freenode IRC, what we're looking at is called a *client side decoration* by the Gnome developers, and hides the window manager bar and replaces it with something inside Gedit itself. So, no amount of configuring GTK will help in this case.

Other people didn't like this sudden change, either. So, someone posted a way to downgrade Gedit to an earlier version before this dramatic change here:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-gedit-3-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Another alternative, however, is a little harder to install, with a method from Github that lets you customize the existing version:

https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to use a theme that has the same icons in gtk and in openbox. I found out that numix has this, I prefer the blue theme so I will use that as an example. In 18.04 numix is in the repos (don't know if it is in 16.04) so you have to:

```
$ sudo apt install numix-blue-gtk-theme
```

Then change the theme in "Control" and in "Window Border" tabs from personalization and behavior (sorry if the names are not correct, I have the system in spanish, I asssume this are the translations) to numixBlue.

This will solve your problem, however, now the panel is dark, so the icons won't see well. Change the icon theme, you can use "lubuntu-dark-panel". There might still be an issue with the fonts that might still be dark. To change this you have to go to panel preferences and in the second tab change the font color.